# Postgresql Trigger example

Tags: postgresql

I created a trigger when a row updated trigger will change that row. When I update a column I get an error. How can I solve?

> ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
>   HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ynt_call()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
     IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
       UPDATE ynt.a_test SET date_time = now();
    END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
 END;
 $$ language 'plpgsql';
 CREATE TRIGGER update_call AFTER UPDATE ON ynt.a_test FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE ynt_call();
```

Comment: It looks you are in an infinite loop. To change the values in your trigger use the **new** and **old** keywords.

Comment: You should have looked closer to the example in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you're looping until the end of time, because you are updating row when updating row. You should set the field date_time using the special variable [`new`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ynt_call()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
     IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
       new.date_time = now();
    END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
 END;
 $$ language 'plpgsql';
 CREATE TRIGGER update_call AFTER UPDATE ON ynt.a_test FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE     PROCEDURE ynt_call();
```